# Trouble understanding the usage of word "whose"

Tags: grammar

Consider the following sentence: Show that if matrix A has rank one, then A = x.y^T for some vectors x and y whose entries are nonnegative and sum to one.

Is the interpretation that the nonnegativity refers to the elements in vectors x and y correct, or does the word "whose" somehow refer to the matrix A?

Comment: It refers to x and y. 'Whose'  follows x and y directly so will relate to them as the nearest items.  I'm afraid that any discussion of the mathematics of probability matrices is outside the scope of EL&U as this site is specifically about the English language. You might get an answer from the Stack Exchange mathematics forum.

Answer (score 0):

Despite its appearance, this is not about mathematics; it is about English. *whose* refers to the vectors. A simple parallel might be: “If hygiene is important, then attention should be paid to those whose clothes are dirty.” In this example, *whose* refers to the immediately preceding *those* (who have dirty clothes) and not to *hygiene* or *attention*. Understanding the mathematics adds nothing to the question or the answer. Mathematics is not an alternative universe divorced from the conventions of grammar.

Comment: What about this example? _When tigers are living close to people, those known to be violent should be shot._ Far too simplistic an answer, and already covered on ELU.

Comment: I have a tendency to blabber whenever I am presenting a question. I will correct the the question to a more appropriate format if that was what you meant.